# How do I print to screen while accepting input that doesnt get deleted and echoed

Tags: python, multithreading, input, output, simultaneous

I have found the following code:

```
import threading
from time import sleep
import os
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = True
    def foo(self):
        while(self.running):
            os.system( [ 'clear', 'cls' ][ os.name == 'nt' ] )
            sleep(2)
    def getUserInput(self):
        x = ''
        while(x != 'e'):
            x = raw_input('Enter value: ')
        self.running = False
    def go(self):
        th1 = threading.Thread(target=self.foo)
        th2 = threading.Thread(target=self.getUserInput)
        th1.start()
        th2.start()
t = test()
t.go()
```

But everytime it clears the screen it clears everything, including what I type. I need something that clears the screen but lets me type and what I type doesnt clear when the screen clears. I need the screen to clear every two seconds and accept input whenever.

Comment: clear the screen after you type ... I dont think you want to have a clearscreen in its own thread ...

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking can't work, because tools like cls are not aware of things like the raw_input() taking place elsewhere, so they can't preserve some of the screen content. What you need is to coordinate that. I see two possible approaches:

- Don't clear the screen while waiting for input, i.e. just signal to the cleanup thread to wait while you are asking for input from the user.
- Use a low-level library to access the screenbuffer, allowing you to preserve the prompt. I think Python has its "curses" implementation that should allow you to do that.

What you should do though is that you take a step back and describe on a more abstract level what you want to achieve. You are asking here how to achieve a certain solution that is IMHO flawed from the beginning. If you described the initial goal instead, someone will come up with an approach that works better.